# Orthogonality with respect to a norm

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $x,y$ be two vectors in a normed vector space.

What does it mean when it is said that two vectors are orthogonal with respect to a norm and does it imply that $\Vert x\Vert^2+\Vert y\Vert^2=\Vert x+y\Vert^2$?

(If an inner product is given, then it is clear to me that orthogonality means $\langle x,y\rangle =0$. If in inner product is given, it is also clear to me that $\Vert x\Vert^2+\Vert y\Vert^2=\Vert x+y\Vert^2$ (Pythagoras).)

Comment: If you don't have an inner product then you don't have orthogonality since it's defined when the inner product of two vectors is zero. However in a lot of use cases for orthogonality the condition can be replaced with saying the projection of one vector onto another is the zero vector.

Comment: I am just wondering about the formulation "orthogonal with respect to the norm . . ."

Comment: "orthogonal with respect to the norm . . ." Are you sure in this case that the norm isn't induced by an inner product? what reference are you using maybe we can see the context

Comment: I am referring to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.05967v2.pdf. On page 22, at the beginning of the proof, it is said that $f^{n+1}-\rho^{n+1}\mathcal{M}$ and $\rho^{n+1}\mathcal{M}$ are orthogonal with respect to $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{2,\gamma}$. The norm is defined on page 12.

Comment: In that paper it cites the norm $|| \cdot ||_{2,\gamma}$. This is the norm of an inner product space. From page 6 "On the second hand, by choosing to adapt the L
2 hypocoercivity method rather than the H1
method, we avoid the burden of estimating derivatives of the solution and dealing with commutators coming from the choice of discrete derivative operators. Thus the numerical analysis
turns out to be almost identical to what is done in the continuous case." It seems this norm is for the $L^2$ space (please check I'm not sure what the $\gamma$ is for here), which has the $L^2$ inner product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notion of orthogonality exists in normed vector spaces only if it exists an inner product. Sometimes in general algebra you will find different notion of orthogonality using $\hom(\ast,\ast)$ but not in the case of a normed space.

You can easily check if you norm is euclidian (from a scalar product) thanks to the polar formulae, using $\|x+y\|^2$ and $\|x-y\|^2$. But orthogonality does not make sense for non euclidian norm, try with $\|\ast\|_1$ or $\|\ast\|_\infty$...

Often there is a small $2$ as index of the norm when it's euclidian (as it does in you reference).

Here you inner product is
$$\langle f, g \rangle_{2,\gamma} \sum_{(i,j) \in \mathcal{I} \times \mathcal{J}} \bar{f_{i,j}} g_{i,j} \gamma_{i,j} \Delta x_{i} \Delta v_j.$$

(Replace euclidian with hermitian in your case)

Comment: Could you rewrite the definition of the norm?

Comment: Yes, it is defined as
$$
\Vert g\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2:=\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{J}}\vert g_{ij}\vert^2\gamma_j\Delta x_i\Delta v_j
$$

Comment: I edited my answer :)

Comment: Maybe you don't see that easily but this is the only inner product that gives this norm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146687/discussion-between-jules-besson-and-selector).

Comment: If the inner product is defined as you wrote, where does the absolute value $\vert 
 g_{ij}\vert^2$ in the induced norm come from and why isn't it $\vert f_{ij}g_{ij}\vert$ in the definition of the inner product?

Comment: @selector $|z|^2 = z \bar{z}$ and if we were to put $|fg|$ it would not be hermitian because it would not be linear